# Determine length of string in the external file

Tags: c++, file, io

I saved my data into a external file in this format

```
Line 1: Name1|Address1
Line 2: Name2|Address2
```

Now, I'm going to read this data back to my program. I want to store the name in the variable NAME which is an array of character. However, my instructor requires the NAME array have to be dynamically allocated. For this reason, I can not just declare

```
name[100];
```

So, what is the efficient way determine the length of the name in the file so that I can use it to allocate my string.

Comment: Are "Line 1:" and "Line 2:" part of the line itself? Or are the lines just "Name|Address"?

Comment: Did the instructor say you have to dynamically allocate an array or dynamically allocate memory for storage? Also is it the storage of each individual name you're after or how to allocate memory to hold all the names?

Comment: To Marlon: Line1 and Line 2 are not part of the line.

Comment: To Tod: He requires me to somehow scan the data in the text file to determine the length of the Name or Address so that it can be stored nicely in a dynamically allocated array based on its length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The brute-force method is to:
1. Set array size to zero.
2. if array size needs to be expanded:
2.1. allocate a new array that is 1 larger than the old array.
2.2. copy all the characters from previous array to new array.
2.3. append new character to new array.
3. increment array size variable.

There are variations on the size to allocate.  Some *string* implementations double the size of the old array.  Others use a fibonacci sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Read it in as a std::string and then call name.size()? You can split on "|" to get just the name in the first part.

Comment: It sounds to me like the instructor wants students to learn to read input lengths and dynamically allocate arrays. If so, simply reading into an std::string kinda circumvents that...

Comment: rob05c is correct, the instructor required me to go into the text file and determine the length of the string and then use this length to allocate a new array of characters. Also, he didn't allow string class to be used.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this does follows your instructor's directions, but the C++ way is to use `std::string` (since you tagged as C++) as opposed to an array of characters.

```
std::ifstream file("data.txt");
std::string name;
std::string address;

while (file) {
  std::getline(file, name, '|');
  std::getline(file, address);
  std::cout << "Name: " << name << "Address: " << address << "\n";
}
```

`std::getline` will read all the characters up to the vertical bar and store that value in `name`, and then read the rest of the characters up to the new line and store that value in `address`. If you want the number of characters in `name`, just call `name.size()`.

Comment: He required me to use array of character